# Buddhism texts which have least amount of disinformation

Tags: reference-request

I am interested in learning about Buddhism.

But I want to learn it from teachings of Buddha or other those texts which have not disinformed over the course of history.

For example , if you read the book: https://books.google.co.in/books/about/History_Of_Hindu_Imperialism.html?id=51dWPgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y

you will come to know how Hindu priestly caste ( Brahmins)  were keen to do harm Buddhism as they were against equality. I think there is a possibility disinformation might have added in buddist texts in other regions of the world also.

> So, can you please tell which text about buddhism contains least amount of disinformation and are best to learn about buddhism for a beginner?

I shall be really thankful!

Comment: disinformation is definitely the wrong word. buddhism is a syncretic religion and not only the buddha has authority in it. if you simply mean "truest" then the question is opinion based

Comment: I feel the core teachings of the Buddha that he taught over and over again in different ways are the most authentic teachings that always fit with themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Buddhists texts acknowledge the Four Noble Truths. The Four Noble Truths are not disinformation. They are simply the Four Noble Truths. The Four Noble Truths are not obvious and they are worth studying in depth:

> [MN141:8.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn141/en/sujato#mn141:8.1): “Near Benares, in the deer park at Isipatana, the Realized One, the perfected one, the fully awakened Buddha rolled forth the supreme Wheel of Dhamma. And that wheel cannot be rolled back by any ascetic or brahmin or god or Māra or Brahmā or by anyone in the world.
> [MN141:8.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn141/en/sujato#mn141:8.2): It is the teaching, advocating, establishing, clarifying, analyzing, and revealing of the four noble truths.
> [MN141:8.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn141/en/sujato#mn141:8.3): What four?
> [MN141:9.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn141/en/sujato#mn141:9.1): The noble truths of suffering, the origin of suffering, the cessation of suffering, and the practice that leads to the cessation of suffering.

The Buddha also instructs us to determine by our own practice what is true. We have to study and practice with proper attention to what is skillful in the context of the Four Noble Truths.

> [MN80:16.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn80/en/sujato#mn80:16.5): Let a sensible person come—neither devious nor deceitful, a person of integrity. I teach and instruct them.
> [MN80:16.6](https://suttacentral.net/mn80/en/sujato#mn80:16.6): Practicing as instructed they will soon know and see for themselves,

One can get lost in the vast sea of books about Buddhism. But at some point, we always end up studying the suttas and discussing them with teachers and good spiritual friends.  The Pali Canon or Tipitaka is an excellent resource that has been extensively verified and compared with other historical references in many countries.  We no longer speak Pali, and therefore must rely on translations into our own language. Such translations can be found in many places (e.g., [suttacentral.net](https://suttacentral.net/general-guide-sujato?lang=en)). However, in our search for truth we will often need to learn some Pali for the clearest understanding.

Comment: if the 4NTs are not understood, mistranslated, etc, they also become disinformation.

Answer (score 1):

There are Three Refugees, namely, The Buddha, The Dhamma & The Noble Sangha.

The Dhamma is defined as follows:

> ‘The Dhamma is well expounded by the Blessed One, directly visible, immediate, inviting one to come and see, applicable, to be personally experienced by the wise.'
>
> [SN 16.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn16.3/en/bodhi?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

It follows, the Buddha taught as follows:

> “Do you speak only of what you have known, seen and understood for yourselves?”
>
> “Yes, venerable sir.”
>
> [MN 38](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/bodhi)

Therefore, if you wish to learn Buddhism, it is ideal to view thus interpret the teachings as something your mind must experience.

Answer (score 0):

I like Ven. Bhikkhu Bodhi's work. He's like the go-to monk in the West. I have all his books and he made several major works on the Nikayas. My dream is that he will one day make a translation of The Dhammapada.